# Getting Error: System.NotSupportedException when Date Comparison

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, android-sqlite

So i am trying to retrieve an instance of the class "Sugar" for a specific date using this method in my UserDatabse.cs class:

```
public List<Sugar> GetSugarDate(DateTime dt)  
{  
    var bld = database.Table<Sugar>().Where(mi => mi.Time.Date == dt.Date).ToList();  
    return bld;  
}
```

*Keep in mind that the app doesn't have any instance of Sugar at the moment so the Date comparison is between a null and an actual date. I think that is causing the error, any solution would be appreciated.

The call to this method is made like this in another class:

```
DateTime Time = DateTime.Now;

ObservableCollection<Image> Sugar_Count = new ObservableCollection<Image>();
Image s = new Image();
s.Source = "drawable/soda.png";
var xa = App.Database.GetSugarDate(Time);
```

The class Sugar.cs is defined as follows:

```
public class Sugar
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public int DrinkCount { get; set; }

    public Sugar()
    {
        Time = DateTime.Now;
        DrinkCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Now the error is get is as follows:

> System.NotSupportedException: Member access failed to compile expression at  SQLite.TableQuery'1[T].CompileExpr(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, System.Collections.Generic.List'1[T]queryArgs)[0x006cc]in <9b4aaa861238418bec74a2ddde70f09>:0 at  SQLite.TableQuery'1[T].CompileExpr(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, System.Collections.Generic.List'1[T]queryArgs)[0x0009d]in <9b4aaa861238418bec74a2ddde70f09>:0 at  SQLite.TableQuery'1[T].CompileExpr(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, System.Collections.Generic.List'1[T]queryArgs)[0x0005f]in <9b4aaa861238418bec74a2ddde70f09>:0 at SQLite.TableQuery'1[T].CompileExpr(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, System.Collections.Generic.List'1[T]queryArgs)[0x00008]in <9b4aaa861238418bec74a2ddde70f09>:0 at
> System.Collections.Generic.List'1[T]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[T]collection)[0x00062] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/generic/list.cs:98 .....

The error occurs at this specific line:

```
var bld = database.Table<Sugar>().Where(mi => mi.Time.Date == dt.Date).ToList();
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: I guess you mistake is at `mi.Time.Date`. If there's no 'mi' at your database, it will throw a null reference exception. Try to code this way: `mi?.Time.Date`.

Comment: Doing so yields an inline error: an expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the expression can not be translated to SQL.

```
mi => mi.Time.Date
```

You can try using:

```
var bld = database.Table<Sugar>().ToList().Where(mi => mi.Time.Date == dt.Date).ToList();
```

> Accessing to the Date part of a `DateTime` column (`mi.Time.Date`) can not be translated to SQL using Linq, for this reason, your statement failed initially. So, using `ToList` fetches all records in memory allowing us to query with **Linq to Object** method not **Linq to SQLite**.

Comment: The code is compiling with your answer, but how is it different than what i already have?

Comment: this is not a good solution as the .ToList will load entire table records in memory ! But this is why it works : it first loads all data in memory and then query the in memory data instead of trying to convert the predicate to sql statement (which triggers the exception as it cannot translate the predicate to sql statement).

Answer (score 0):

Its a little janky, but I have got this to work:

```cs
public List<Sugar> GetSugarDate(DateTime dt)
{
    var dayStart = dt.Date.AddDays(-1);
    var dayEnd = dt.Date.AddDays(1);

    var bld = database.Table<Sugar>().Where(mi => mi.Time > dayStart && mi.Time < dayEnd).ToList();
    return bld;
}
```

Also make sure you initialize your database connection with:

```cs
SQLiteConnection database = new SQLiteConnection(_path,false);
```

If you are querying a nullable DateTime

Answer (score 0):

The little janky code worked for me

```html
 var dayStart = stockDate.Date.AddDays(-1);
var dayEnd = stockDate.Date.AddDays(1);

return  db.Table<ProductStock>().Where(x => x.StockDate > dayStart && x.StockDate < dayEnd).ToListAsync();
```